# Error using react-read-more-read-less with data from a dabase

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a website with react that maps through an instructors table and displays the instructors' image, name, and bio.  I'm trying to use the react-read-more-read-less component to initially show 300 characters then show a Read More link to display all the text.  If I hard code the text in the  component it works perfectly but when I try to pull the data in from the db, I get an error that children.substr is not a function.

Here is the code:

```
<ReactReadMoreReadLess
  readMoreClassName="readMoreClassName"
  charLimit={300}
  readMoreText="Read More"
  readLessText="Read Less"
 >
   {parse(inst.instructorBio)}
 </ReactReadMoreReadLess>
```

If I just use {inst.instructorBio} it works find but displays the p tags p.

I even tried to write a toggleShow function and it worked but it expanded all the instructors bios and I wasn't able to figure out how to only expand the one clicked.

Pares is from a npm package I installed to render the data correctly without showing the p tags.  The pagckage is html-react-parser.

Comment: Try this one: {JSON.stringify(parse(inst.instructorBio))}

Comment: That gives me a new error:  Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'Object'
    |     property '_context' -> object with constructor 'Object'
    --- property 'Provider' closes the circle
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)

Comment: what is `parse` function?

Comment: Its a react library html-react-parser that renders the data correctly without showing the html tags.

Comment: Do you need plain text or text witch formatted by tags  inside `ReactReadMoreReadLess`?

Comment: I need the text formatted really just paragraphs, otherwise it works great but shows the <p> tags.

Comment: ```console.log``` the data your getting from ```db```, check the format  whether it is ```HTML``` string or ```JSON```

Comment: The console.log shows the data with the <p> tags... <p> Scott Moore began judo in 1988....</p>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First solution:**

The error occurs because only text is expected as a child element. Only text has a substring (`substr`) feature.

My solution will require further refinement but may be a good start. Use replacement for paragraphs. Maybe this function is enough:

```
const convert = (html) => html.replace(/<p>/gi, "\n").replace(/<\/p>/gi, "");
```

In order to use `\n` we need to wrap the element in `pre`

```
return (
   <pre>
     <ReactReadMoreReadLess charLimit={5}>
       {inst.instructorBio}
     </ReactReadMoreReadLess>
   </pre>
);
```

This solution preserves line breaks well, but for the rest you will have to work with styles to make lines behave like paragraphs.

For wrap text in `pre`:

```
pre {
 white-space: pre-wrap;       /* css-3 */
 white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
 white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */
 white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
 word-wrap: break-word;       /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
}
```

**Second solution for many paragraphs — own component:**

The `-webkit-line-clamp` CSS property allows limiting of the contents of a block to the specified number of lines.

```js
const Fragment = React.Fragment

const MoreLessText = ({children}) => {
  const [more, setMore] =  React.useState(false)
  return(
    <Fragment>
      <div className={"text" + (more ? '' : ' less')} >
        {children} 
      </div> 
      <span onClick={() => setMore(!more)}> {/* toggle state*/}
        { more ? 'Show Less' : 'Show More'}
      </span>
    </Fragment> 
  )
}

const App = () => {
 return (
   <table border="1">
      <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <MoreLessText>
                <p>
                  1) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore fugiat cumque, aliquam minus repellat voluptates adipisci. Consectetur, voluptatem nam quasi alias minima, nihil tenetur odit, a atque deleniti maiores est?
                </p>              
              </MoreLessText>
            </td>
          </tr> 
          <tr>
            <td>
              <MoreLessText>
                <p>
                  2) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore fugiat cumque, aliquam minus repellat voluptates adipisci. Consectetur, voluptatem nam quasi alias minima, nihil tenetur odit, a atque deleniti maiores est?
                </p>              
              </MoreLessText>
            </td>
          </tr> 
      </tbody>
   </table>
 )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.text{
  width: 300px;
}
.less {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 1;
          line-clamp: 1; 
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">
```

Comment: That works but I'll have to figure out how to remove the indenting of the pre tag.

Comment: I got it to not indent with white-space: pre-line but I can't make the text go all the way across the screen.

Comment: what about the second solution? [That's why](https://github.com/giatro/react-read-more-read-less/blob/50ef1c54864bbb2bb10c50b0a9969d1173afd179/src/index.js#L14) an error occurs, at the same time this is the source of the component

Comment: @StephenScottMoore I added style for `wrap` text in `pre` it may be helpfull

Comment: That works but I have multiple instructors so when I click on read more, they all read more.  That didn't happen with ReactReadMoreReadLess, just the other issue.

Comment: @StephenScottMoore Which of the solutions are you trying first or second? I want to make an example with multiple instructors. Maybe I need to know a little more about your layout because blocks can't expand and shrink together.

Comment: I updated second solution

Comment: Genius!  That prety close to what I had and it worked great when the text was hard coded but when I fetched it from the db is when I started having all the trouble!

Thank you so much!